# Оборачивающие тэги для каждого элемента коллекции JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Есть класс Entity, который нужно серилизовать в XML, используя JAXB.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entities")

public class Entity {
private Set<Integer> fields;

public void setAllFields(Set<Integer> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "entity")
@XmlElement(name = "field")
public Set<Integer> getAllFields() {
    return fields;
   }
}
```

На выходе получается:

```
<entities>
   <entity>
      <field>1</field>
      <field>2</field>
   </entity>
</entities>
```

А нужно чтобы было:

```
<entities>
   <entity>
      <field>1</field>
   </entity>
   <entity>
      <field>2</field>
   </entity>
</entities>
```

Можно ли добиться такого, не вводя дополнительные классы и переменные? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: На сколько знаю - никак